# How to use np.where() inside an array with instances of a class?

Tags: python, class, numpy

I have the following class:

```
class IdFuns(object):
    def __init__(self,i,p,v,u):
        self.i = i
        self.p = p
        self.v = v
        self.u = u
```

When I put inside a loop I get the following array with instances of the class:

```
   array([
   <__main__.IdFuns object at 0x7fc8362e8250>,
   <__main__.IdFuns object at 0x7fc8362e8290>,
   <__main__.IdFuns object at 0x7fc8362e82d0>,
   <__main__.IdFuns object at 0x7fc8362e8310>,
   <__main__.IdFuns object at 0x7fc8362e8350>,
   <__main__.IdFuns object at 0x7fc8362e8390>,
   <__main__.IdFuns object at 0x7fc8362e83d0>,
   <__main__.IdFuns object at 0x7fc8362e8410>,
   <__main__.IdFuns object at 0x7fc8362e8450>,
   <__main__.IdFuns object at 0x7fc8362e8490>,
   <__main__.IdFuns object at 0x7fc8362e84d0>,
   <__main__.IdFuns object at 0x7fc8362e8510>,
   <__main__.IdFuns object at 0x7fc8362e8550>], dtype=object)
```

I want to know how do I use np.where() to search if I have an instance  with **.i = 1**, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.i` is an attribute of the *individual items* in your object array, rather than of the array itself. You therefore need to loop over these items in Python, for example using a list comprehension:

```
bool_idx = [item.i == 1 for item in object_array]
```

This can then be passed as the first argument to `np.where`:

```
locs = np.where(bool_idx)
```

---

In general I would suggest you avoid using `np.object` arrays. Since they don't support vectorized operations they don't really offer any significant performance improvement over a standard Python `list`. It looks to me as though you might be better off using a [structured numpy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html) or a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Comment: Thank you! It will help me a lot.